# jQuery - On scroll remove class above and below

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, addclass, removeclass

This is my first post and question here. Please look at the image below:

[image]

I have the page with a block element divs (example, one div in a row, with height of 100px, and 30 divs one under another). I need solution which will add class to divs which are in "red" offset, and while I'm scrolling up or down to remove same class to divs which are out of offset.

I know it has to be something with offsets, but I can't really find solution. I'm trying to do this with jQuery.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please post some code? SO is about coding, so without any code, no one can help you. You can also create a Fiddle quickly [here](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I don't have any solution, but here is what I need - https://jsfiddle.net/3yto6ax2/

Comment: Practically, you need each block in viewport to have class `standard`, is that correct?

Comment: No just in viewport, in "offset". For example, "offset" is viewport and plus 300px above and below viewport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate elements position relative to viewport you need to check [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), than it is easy:

```js
function isInScreenPlusOffset(el, offset) {
    var rect = el[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= -offset &&
        rect.bottom <= $(window).height()+offset
    );
};
$(window).on('scroll', function(e){
    $('.basic').each(function(i) {
        var thisBox = $(this);
        thisBox.toggleClass('standard', isInScreenPlusOffset(thisBox , 300));
    });
});
```

```css
.basic {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.standard {
    border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>

<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>

<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>

<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>

<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>

<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>

<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>

<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>

<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>

<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
<div class="basic">
</div>
```

Also on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yto6ax2/2/).